# Classe PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCase not found

Tags: php, composer, phpunit, dbunit

Galera

Quando eu rodo um teste no phpunit cuja classe extende de \PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCase eu recebo essa mensagem:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCase' not found
```

Mas quando eu rodo um teste de uma classe que extende de \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase funciona!

Esse é o meu composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "6.0.7",
    "phpunit/dbunit": "^3.0"
  }
}
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Já verificou na pasta `vendor` se o `dbunit` foi instalado corretamente?

Comment: Esta usando o php 7 na interface de linha de comando (CLI)? Se não tiver certeza `php -v`

Comment: Anderson, o que você quer dizer com instalado corretamente?

Comment: Olá, Guilherme. Sim, php 7. Confirmado pelo comando php -v.

Comment: Existe o diretório `dbunit` referente ao repositório dentro de `vendor`? Talvez, quando você executou `composer install` tenha dado algum erro que tenha passado despercebido.

Comment: O diretório dbunit existe sim. Pensei nisso antes, mas tinha verificado. Aparentemente está tudo normal.